# trouble saving bitmap to file in C#

Tags: c#, image, bitmap, save

I'm trying to save a bitmap to a file, all the examples and tutorials I have found suggest using this line of code to do so-

```
        private void saveImageToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // Save the fractal image
    {
        SaveFileDialog dialog = new SaveFileDialog();
        if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            fractal.Save("myfile.png", ImageFormat.Png);
        }
    }
```

When I execute the code by click the save image button (which calls the above method) a save dialog appears but both the file name field and file type field are empty. I select a location to save to and give the file a name - e.g. bitmap.png then check the location and nothing has saved.

I have also checked the debug folder and nothing has appeared there ether.

I'm assuming I'm not far off or that I've made a silly mistake elsewhere any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: We need more than 1 line of code.

Comment: apologies - i realised after posting but i couldn't find the edit button!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using the [SaveFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.savefiledialog.aspx) class, you need to set the `Filter` and `DefaultExt` properties to get the file extensions to show up.

You then read the `FileName` property as the argument to your `Save()` call